# Yfinance remove time from the datetime index column

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

[image]

I want only the date shows yyy-mm-dd, not as in the pictures, I'm learning python and actually I do not know how to do that, thanks for your help

```
import yfinance as yf

tesla = yf.Ticker('TSLA')
tesla = pd.DataFrame(tesla.history(perido='1d'))
tesla = tesla[['Close', 'Open', 'High', 'Low']]

print(tesla)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are retrieving the open, high, low, close, and adj close price. You can actually just use `yf.download`.

```
df = yf.download('TSLA',start='2022-10-10',end='2022-10-11')
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
 
                  Open        High  ...   Adj Close    Volume
Date                                ...                      
2022-10-10  223.929993  226.990005  ...  222.960007  67715000

[1 rows x 6 columns]

df[['Close','Open','High','Low']]

                 Close        Open        High         Low
Date                                                      
2022-10-10  222.960007  223.929993  226.990005  218.360001
```

### Update

To remove the time from the date, you can use `dt.normalize` when your column is already a datetime.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.normalize()

df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got the same answer, the date shows: "2022-10-10 00:00:00-04:00"
I'm using jupyter lab on Anaconda, maybe my configuration contains an error

import yfinance as yf
df = yf.download('TSLA',start='2022-10-10',end='2022-10-11')
df[['Close','Open','High','Low']]



[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[177]:
Close Open High Low
Date    
2022-10-10 00:00:00-04:00 222.960007 223.929993 226.990005 218.360001

Comment: I have updated the solution, perhaps you can try this out?

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked!